# Shopee open platform API possible to set multiple app category in 1 app?

Tags: shopee

I'm new as Shopee open platform API I trying to create a app and now I can using to auth a test shop to get access token already. Now my app type is Customer service I want to use a chat API and I want to use my app to get product comment and reply comment too but this API is in product management category.

My question :

- If I want to setting my app to using 2 category it is a possible to do that? I can't set it to use 2 category as a same time is can set only one of this.
- In chat API if my app is under developing is can't request to use that permission right? (Shopee reject my request for some reason) I need to go live my app first and in the next step it can request to use chat API?